# Hook on monitor turning on

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

I have turned computer monitor off using this command

```
SendMessage(f.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr)SC_MONITORPOWER, (IntPtr)(turnOff ? 2 : -1));
```

is it possible to hook monitor turning on to prevent it or execute some function?

Comment: I want to know is it possible to prevent switching on of the monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373195%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: it is great answer. I want to know is it possible to prevent switching on of the monitor.